# What is the use of struts2-jQuery plugin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I want to know the advantages of using Struts2-jQuery plug-in ?? What is its use ?? Also some support from where to study as I did not find any tutorials.

Comment: Refer this for clear idea about Struts2 jQuery plugin https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag

Answer (score 2):

Advantages - that strictly depends on your use. If you don't want to write the jquery code yourself, then the plugin gives handful of pre-written features to use.

I've been using it for more than 2 years now and in my case, I write custom jquery too where-ever required, since it's not a good style to re-invent the wheel. So I use the plugin where it is helpful and where it can't be applied directly or with minor tweaks. At times, I prefer writing my own jquery.

Here are some links from where you can start :

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action

https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/ - It contains all UI widgets and possible interactions with sample

http://struts2-jquery.appspot.com/home.action

I had also put up a few struts2-jquery-plugin examples on my [github](https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples)