# What is the difference between Struts 2 and Struts 2 jQuery tags?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts-tags, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am new to Struts 2. I wanted to know the difference between Struts 2 and Struts 2 jQuery tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is used for [Struts2 core tag library](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/using-tags.html),

> The framework provides a tag library decoupled from the view
> technology. In this section, we describe each tag in general terms,
> such as the attributes it supports, what the behaviors are, and so
> forth. Most tags are supported in all template languages (see JSP
> Tags, Velocity Tags, and FreeMarker Tags), but some are currently only
> specific to one language. Whenever a tag doesn't have complete support
> for every language, it is noted on the tag's reference page.
>
> The types of tags can be broken in to two types: generic and UI.
> Besides function and responsibility, the biggest difference between
> the two is that the HTML tags support templates and themes. In
> addition to the general tag reference, we also provide examples for
> using these generic tags in each of the support languages.

the second is added via plugin. It adds/replaces the [Ajax being used by struts2 dojo plugin](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/ajax.html).

> Dojo plugin is deprecated
>
> The Dojo plugin will be deprecated on Struts 2.1
>
> Struts 2.0 versus Struts 2.1 and the Dojo tags
>
> The easiest way to get documentation for Struts 2.0 Dojo tag usage is
> to look at older Struts 2 documentation, like the Struts 2.0.11 Ajax
> tags wiki documentation.

Now this plugin is deprecated and [struts2 jquery plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=119537#content/view/119537) could be used instead.

> A Plugin for the popular java web framework struts2 to provide ajax functionality and UI Widgets based on the jQuery javascript framework.

Comment: http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action, follow this link, if want to start learning Struts2 jQuery plugin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808002/what-is-the-use-of-struts2-jquery-plugin. This helps me a lot to find some links for Struts2 jQuery plugin.